# Nature of solutions above the maximal equilibrium solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Q. Consider the ordinary differential equation $y^{\prime}=y(y-1)(y-2)$. Which of the following statements is true?

(1) If $y(0)=0.5$ then $y$ is decreasing

(2) If $y(0)=1.2$ then $y$ is increasing

(3) If $y(0)=2.5$ then $y$ is unbounded

(4) If $y(0)<0$ then $y$ is bounded below

I can deal with options 1 and 2 since the function $f(t,y)=y(y-1)(y-2)$ is locally Lipschitz in any compact neighbourhood of $(0, y(0))$. The solutions distinct from equilibrium solutions cannot intersect with equilibrium solutions to preserve the uniqueness. But how to deal with the possible solutions above $y=2$ and below $y=0$? Of course the derivative $y'>0$ for the solution above $y=2$ but I feel it is not sufficient to say the solutions blows up to infinity. If there is no more equilibrium solution, how  can we say the solutions above $y=2$ blows up? Or if any solution is asymptotic to $y=y_0$, is it necessary to say $y=y_0$ is an equilibrium solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y(0)>2$, then $y'\ge (y-2)^3>0$ in forward direction. It is well-known or easy to check that this dynamic diverges in finite time.

The same if $y(0)<0$, then $y'\le y^3<0$ which diverges to minus infinity in finite time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the analytical approach in the other post you received, it is possible to combine that with a [*direction field*](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_211_Calculus_II/Chapter_8%3A_Introduction_to_Differential_Equations/8.2%3A_Direction_Fields_and_Numerical_Methods) plot.

For your particular example this is

[image]

Notice what is happening to the slope field above two and below zero.

Here is another view of it with many initial conditions

[image]